# Save the results of a dataframe into csv

Tags: r

I use this option:

```r
write.csv(df2, "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

```
Error in utils::write.table(df2, "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.csv", row.names = FALSE,: 
unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

in the view df2 it seems to be as it should be. How can I change the df2 in order to save it properly?

Comment: You have a list column in your data frame.  there are a few generic approaches to trying to 'fix' it but the best one is to look at your data and work out the issue.  Can you `dput(head(df2))` and paste it into your question?

Comment: do you have a cilumn of type "list"? use `str(df2)` to check